# Access violation while loading DLL library

Tags: c++, dll, load, access-violation

I have a library with function `int Message()` that I need to call from my program.

my program (c++ msvc2010):

```
typedef int (_cdecl*pproc)();
pproc out;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(L"messager.dll");
    if(hLib == NULL) return 0;

    out = (pproc)GetProcAddress(hLib,"Message");
    printf("out %i", (out == NULL)); //0

    if (out == NULL) {
        printf("Error getting Address");
    }
    else {
        int j = out(); // Error Access violation
    }
    FreeLibrary(hLib);
    return 0;
}
```

Error: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location "0x0045a780

function from dll (c mingw):

```
__declspec(dllexport) int Message()  {
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("1"), TEXT("1"), MB_OK);
    return main(0, NULL);
}
```

dll dumpbin:

```
    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00011AA0 Message
```

Comment: what does the "main" function in the DLL do ? Seems suspicious to me.

Comment: main does a lot of different things), but it is not important because MessageBox is not called, even after replacing the main(0, NULL) to 0

Comment: Are you sure the `Message` function is compiled using the _cdecl calling convention ? Might be a mismatch caused by the compiler.

Comment: If you mean exe, then yes (the first line in my example)

Comment: both of them, actually, calling conventions have to match. Especially as you declared the function pointer with a _cdecl type. I would recommend that exported DLL functions use an explicit calling convention anyways.

Comment: __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Message() Unfortunately it does not help. I do not know if this is important, but if I rename the dll in the exe, it works as a program

Comment: That sounds pretty fishy.  You can't just build an exe, rename it to a dll and hope it will work.  A dll needs to be relocatable so it can be loaded anywhere in memory.  An exe will typically have its relocation table stripped since it is always loaded at a predictable address.

Comment: Could you help me links or examples of how to do this in C?